# FFMPEG - how to remove the padding in a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video which original dimension is 1920 x 1080. But I was padded with black. I want to set the video with aspect ratio 16:9.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Which way do you want to stretch it? Was it padded from 4:3 to 16:9 or…?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `crop` filter. Let me give you some examples:

If the image has symmetrical black bars, then you only need to specify the output width and height of the image i.e. the first two parameters of the `crop` filter, because it will perform it relative to the center of the image.

If the input has `1920 x 1080` but the actual content has a `2.35:1` aspect ratio, then you would want to crop to `1920 x 816`, so the total height of the black bars is `264` pixels, `132` on each side. A crop for this can be specified in multiple ways:

- `crop = 1920:816` will work since as I mentioned it will perform a symmetrical crop
- `crop= in_w: in_h-264` or `crop= in_w: in_h - 2*132` will do just the same only that it will use placeholders such as `in_w` and `in_h` for the input frame's width and height.

For assymetrical crops you need to also specify the next two parameters of the crop filter which determine the position relative to top-left (`0:0`) of the frame from where the crop is performed.

- For the aforementioned case, this could be done like this: `crop = 1920:816:0:132`, as `0:132` are the coordinates of the pixel in the frame from which you want your crop to occur *downwards and to the right*.

Using the crop filter would require you to re-encode the video, so make sure you use good enough quality parameters.

You can use `ffplay` to test out your crops before actually performing them by specifying the filter there (it also supports it just as `ffmpeg`):

```
ffplay -vf "crop = 1920:816:0:132" input.mkv
```

or by piping the encode output (here done with libx264) to ffplay:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec libx264 -profile:v high -crf 21 -tune film -level 4.1 -acodec copy -vf "crop = 1920:816:0:132" -f mpegts - | ffplay -i -
```

For more clarifications please consult [the documentation of the crop filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) as the explanations are very good.